# Mule Studio: Mule Flow: Use of File

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Within my flow - I am trying to read username pwd from a file based on a key sent by the user.

**Question:**

1. Does Mule allow to read data from the file (it can contain set of
   user keys and every key will have a uname/pwd
2. What connector to use it?

Answer (score 1):

To read a single file, you can use the [Mule Requester Module](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-the-mule-requester-module/).

```
<mulerequester:request resource="file://${my.filename}"/>
```

Comment: This is interesting. I will see if this is a more handy solution.

For now i added what I needed to a property file and loaded the property at start up.

Answer (score 0):

to read a file can use file inbound, the payload after file inbound will be the content of the file

Comment: you can also mentioen the path of that file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of documentation that shows users different ways to read a properties file in Mule flows.

Here are three approaches on how you can do this:

```
Reading a properties file using ${Key} expression
Reading a properties file using ![p[‘Key’]] expression
Reading a properties file using p() function from DataWeave
```